# WooCommerce: Exclude bundles from all coupons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon, woocommerce-product-bundles

I'm using a custom code to prevent products from all coupons.
For that, every product has an extra checkbox in the backend.

The code is mostly based on that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47603782/1788961

You can see the backend checkbox here:

[image: custom checkbox in product general settings metabox]

Everything works fine so far.

But after we've changed our bundles to have the bundled products be priced individually, the checkbox doesn't work anymore.

I guess that the code doesn't apply on the product inside a bundle.

This is the code to make coupons invalid at product level and set the product discount amount to zero:

```
// Make coupons invalid at product level
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product', 'set_coupon_validity_for_excluded_products', 12, 4);
function set_coupon_validity_for_excluded_products($valid, $product, $coupon, $values ){
    if( ! count(get_option( '_products_disabled_for_coupons' )) > 0 ) return $valid;

    $disabled_products = get_option( '_products_disabled_for_coupons' );
    if( in_array( $product->get_id(), $disabled_products ) )
        $valid = false;

    return $valid;
}

// Set the product discount amount to zero
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'zero_discount_for_excluded_products', 12, 5 );
function zero_discount_for_excluded_products($discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon ){
    if( ! count(get_option( '_products_disabled_for_coupons' )) > 0 ) return $discount;

    $disabled_products = get_option( '_products_disabled_for_coupons' );
    if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $disabled_products ) )
        $discount = 0;

    return $discount;
}
```

Is there a way to check the product type of a cart item and disable the coupon on bundled products?

I know how to check for the product type and I tried a few things. But nothing worked so far.

I tried some things and the code from **Howard E** in the answer below. Unfortunately nothing works for now.

But I realised something.

If the bundle has a regular price and a sale price, everything works as it should. But if the bundle product is piced individually (as seen in the screen below), the code doesn't work anymore.

I guess I have to chech if an item is part of a parent bundle item?
Is that possible in the cart?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

I changed the if statements to the following code:

```
if( in_array( $product->get_id(), $disabled_products ) or wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item($cart_item) === true )
```

and:

```
if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $disabled_products ) or wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item($cart_item) === true )
```

By adding `wc_pb_is_bundled_cart_item($cart_item) === true` I could check if the cart item is part of a bundle and exclude the item from any coupon.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to test this, but it would seem that the following should work.

```
// Make coupons invalid at product level.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product', 'set_coupon_validity_for_excluded_products', 12, 4 );
function set_coupon_validity_for_excluded_products( $valid, $product, $coupon, $values ) {

    if ( 'bundle' === $product->get_type() ) {
        $valid = false;
    }

    return $valid;
}

// Set the product discount amount to zero.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_get_discount_amount', 'zero_discount_for_excluded_products', 12, 5 );
function zero_discount_for_excluded_products( $discount, $discounting_amount, $cart_item, $single, $coupon ) {

    $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );

    if ( 'bundle' === $product->get_type() ) {
        $discount = 0;
    }

    return $discount;
}
```

Comment: I tried the code and edited my answer after it. I guess it has something to do with the indivdually priced items in a bundle product. That's why the code doesn't work.